# const is undefined using mobx and typescript

Tags: typescript, mobx

I have the following code

```
export const NavViews = {
    test: "test1",
    test2: "test2"
} as const;
```

When I do

```
export class MainViewsStore {

     @computed
     get isLandingPage() {
        return this.primaryView === NavViews.test;
     }
}
```

When I call the code `this._mainViewsStore.isLandingPage`, it's false even though `this.primaryView === NavViews.test`

I'm using mobx and typescript. The `NavViews.test` is undefined. Has anyone seen a situation like that before?

Comment: Well, there is nothing wrong with this code. Without more information it will be hard to help.

Comment: You need to present a [mre].

Comment: Why the `as const` at the end of the export?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans maybe that's what is causing the failure. not sure why they put const there. Do you think that could be the cause?

Comment: Without the rest of your code that shows how you're importing it (so: [mcve]) no idea, but I'd certainly remove it.